# How to get the scroll bar inside the table when jquery.freezeheader.js is used in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery.freezeheader.js to freeze the headers of table when more data is available.. I am achieving what i want to do. But the scroll bar is getting outside the table.It seems to be bad while if no data in the table is available..

So what i am trying to do is, i need to get the scroll bar inside the table

```
js:
---------
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#fixHeader").freezeHeader({ 'height': '450px' });


});
```

### html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/js/freezeheader/jquery.freezeheader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <table id="fixHeader">
           <tr>
           <thead>
               <th>S.No</th>
               <th>Student Name</th>
               <th>Student Father Name</th>
           </thead>
           </tr>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                   <td>Varun</td>
                     <td>Narayana</td>
               </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                   <td>harika</td>
                     <td>Nagendrudu</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                   <td>Aravind</td>
                     <td>venu</td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: paste your html and js code please

Comment: I have updated the question. Please find

Answer (score 0):

opps in your html code `fixHeader` is an id of your table and in your js you are applying freezheader by class name which is not able please update your js code by

`$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#fixHeader").freezeHeader({ 'height': '450px' });
});`

please comment if is there any issue :) all the best

Comment: And when the "th " are appending dynamically the freeze is applied even the width also. I ave 3 constant header and 10 dynamically added headers , then the freezing is done upto the screen width. but data is scrollable

Comment: may be it is html tag misplace issue try `<tr></tr>` inside the `<thead></thead>`

Comment: I have a clarity that , both the data and headers are dynamic.. then how can we use this freeze concept

Comment: it is not matter that data and header are dynamically or static man I dont know why you are facing this kind of issue i have also used it the main difference is that my table is inside the `<div></div>` nothing else

Comment: Present I am facing the issue right.. i need to have a solution.. I am just exploring but still didn't find any solution..